# iOS: Creating a taller UIToolbar

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitoolbar

[image]

I want to create the UI above. Specifically, a *taller* toolbar. But I need to do so in a way that the underlying UI (i.e. content view) displays accordingly (i.e. underneath the toolbar.

I am familiar with the new UIAppearance options in iOS 5. However, these seem to be more about skinning, not adjust sizes.

I imagine a could make the UI elements and add them to the `window`? But wouldn't that cause sizing issues with the content views. Seems hacky…

So, what would be the way to achieve this UI. Ideally supporting back to iOS 4.2. But an iOS 5 solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Controls/Controls.html) allow you to customized their Controls, the only way to customize is to use customized controls. One way is to use [Custom-UIToolbar](https://github.com/marichka/Custom-UIToolbar) derived from UIView.

Comment: See **Guidelines that Apply Generally to Controls** section.

Comment: Sorry I have attached Mac OS link. Here is iOS HIG link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html

Comment: Thanks. This does answer my question - create a custom control. But I am trying to stay native, so I will probably just end up using the default `UIToolbar` height.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure what functions you want to replicate/make, but you can change the height of your toolbar with this:

```
[toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 60)];
```

This will create for you, a toolbar with 60px of height. Let me know if it's what you want.

Comment: I've seen answers regarding this. But as noted, seems *hackish* and ill advised based on the docs.

Comment: UIToolbar is a UIView like any other, in fact almost every UI have it's __inheritance__. Is _hackish_ do this? `UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 60)];` You're simply telling a button where it belongs. Same thing with the toolbar. `UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 60)];` Your concern is a fear to get rejected by Apple? or are you trying to find a simpler method? Try with IB, i believe that almost all properties you can change there.

Comment: I suppose the following line taken from the Mobile HIG in regard to the device rotation concerned me - *Don’t specify the height of a toolbar programmatically; instead, you can take advantage of the UIBarMetrics constants to ensure that your content fits well.*

Comment: Yes, some controls are indeed already done, so you won't have to change it. But you can _always_ set any `UIView` frame to whatever you want. I don't know what app is that in the image you provided, but my _guess_ is, it's an UIView customized to it's need.

Comment: You can't change the height in IB (that field is inactive). I also confirmed with the docs and other posts that you *should not* change the height. The *right* way to do this is to create a custom toolbar, which I don't want. Thanks for you help.